# Why is my `span` so wide?

Tags: css, html

I have:

```
<div class="soldhere-title-large">
sold here
<span class="title-dot-span">. </span>
in 
</div>
```

The CSS for my span is:

```css
.title-dot-span {
  font-size: 100pt;
  width: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

yet, the span has a lot of space after the `.` content. Any ideas?

Comment: In your CSS you have title-slash-span but in your HTML you have title-dot-span?

Comment: Fixed - type. In my CSS, it's correct

Comment: What is "a lot of space" for you? Your class have `width: 10px`. Is it big or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in your span. The space is 100pt big. This is what's making your span wide.

Comment: This is pretty much it. I don't really know why the space is there in the first place.

Comment: Because I'm using `Jade` and it compiles with a space for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block;` in your CSS.

Comment: Then I might as well use a `div` and then I need to deal with `float`ing

Comment: What about `display: inline-block`?